# Would this question be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

There are quite a few questions about http vs. https. I think the most similar to mine is [Is HTTPS redirecting to HTTP a vulnerability?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76301/is-https-redirecting-to-http-a-vulnerability)

My question is: I visited a website where the login page was secure (https) but the rest of the site was not secure (http). When directed to the payment portal, I initially ended up on a not secure page (http). Can I just add prepend https to the url or could that make it forget what I was paying for and/or would there be some negative side-effects from going there from the http version of the website.
www.imleagues.com is the website in particular. Interestingly, www.imleagues.com/Members/Payment/Paypal.aspx now redirects to https (OSX 10.12.6, chrome) but it still goes to http when redirected to that page after clicking "Buy Spring Pass" (which is quite a few pages away from the homepage; that behavior occurs on OSX 10.12.6 firefox and chrome as well as on RHEL7 firefox).

If you think it's okay then I'll post it on non-meta. If you think it is a duplicate, I'm interested in your explanation. I think it's rather similar but different enough for me to ask. But, I thought I'd check here first in case my intuition is off.

Comment: That is definitely a dupe. It's the same risk described.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Should I delete this post then?

Comment: @RyanFarber No need to delete this post, this is the type of question meta is for.